# IOS TableView first cell Image should start from status bar

Tags: ios, swift, tableview, navigationbar, iphone-x

Created table view in which first cell contains an Image I want this image to overlap with status bar like shown in image below. How to create NavigationBar accordingly?

[image]

Tried following line of code didn't worked for me.

```
tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: -UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame.size.height, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
```

**Also played around with safe area and super view but no luck with that**

Update:

Added top space to superview -90 constraint to tableview now Image is visible in status bar wanted to know is that right way to do or is there any other way

[image]

Found that there is empty black space at top due to navigation controller and navigation bar it is not working until I set top space to super view as -90 following is image

[image]

In storyBoard I can check empty space at top is taken by navigation item

[image]

Comment: Did you consider this? https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1797/_index.html

Comment: its about Preventing the Status Bar from Covering Your View

Comment: Yes but it also explains how to cover it.

Comment: does not solve my problem

Answer (score 4):

set the tableview **top constraint 0 to superview** and in viewDidLoad use the below code:

```
    tableView.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .never

    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .default)
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = true
    self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
```

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried to attach top constraint not to safe area but to superview?

Also you can try this:

```
 self.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .never
```

Comment: @amodkanthe you also can try this,  self.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .never updated my answer

Comment: not working I guess NavigationController casing problem updated question please check

Answer (score 3):

At first, adjust constraint same as below image :

[image: Table Constraint]

And then create Top/Navigation view with three buttons, which should be above tableview with `clear` background colour. Same as in above image. And that top view's `top constraint` should be `top aligned` with `safe area`.

Put below methods into your controller :

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: true)
}

override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: true)
}
```

And now when you run, it will exactly look like what you want.

[image: Table First cell should overwrite navigation bar]

Comment: @amodkanthe Have you tried this ? Or you found any other solution ?

Comment: I don’t want to simulate navigation bar is there any other way to do it without hiding navigation bar

Answer (score 1):

Add top constraints of tableview.top to superview.top

Comment: not working I guess NavigationController casing problem updated question please check

Answer (score 1):

Make tableview top constraint 0 to superview and make the navigation bar transparent. Please use the extension I made in order to make the navigation bar transparent if needed.

```
extension UINavigationController {

    func transparent()  {
        self.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .default)
        self.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
        self.navigationBar.isTranslucent = true // set bartintColor if isTranslucent is false
        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    }

    func nonTransparent() {
        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.75)
        self.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false
        self.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.white
    }

}
```

Comment: Hi this will make bar transparent what about top constraints updated answer please check

Comment: you should make tableView stick to superview to make it look like shown in the image above.

Comment: this makes bar transparent but leaves space at top until and unless i add space -90 it does not work

Comment: It might be because the whole image view is not covered with the image. Try changing content mode of image view to scale to fill or aspect fill with top constraint 0.

Comment: not working I guess NavigationController casing problem updated question please check

Answer (score 0):

You can “Simulate” navigation bar and achieve your goal.

1. Constraints tableView to superview.top 0
2. Set tableview.contentInsetsAdjustmentsBehavior = .never
3. On viewWillAppear call `self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: animated)`
4. Place your back button and other items which should be in navigation bar above table view. Could use tableView’s superview but dont forget to move them above tableView. Use top safe area for them so it will lock like they placed in navigationBar.

Note: This thing will disable edge pan gesture for navigating back.

Answer (score 0):

in order to create that layout:

1. You must pin your tableView to `view.TopAnchor`
2. Set contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior to never `tableView.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .never`
3. Set the imageView's topAnchor inside your cell to `contentView.topAnchor`
4. Set navigationController's background image and shadow image:
   `navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .default)
   navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()`

   let me know if it's all good. it must work